# Adding element if user is in role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I do something like that:

```
 <ul id="menu">
     @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")) {
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Administration", "Index", "Administration")</li>
    }
 </ul>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: No, I think this is the shortest way. If you have multiple different "secure" links then you could implement an extension to HtmlHelper which checks for AuthorizationAttribute on Actions and render only if the user has enough permissions.

Comment: @DanielB hey Dan, why don't you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course the shortest way. Its seems you are building a global menu with links only visible for certain users. You should have a look at `MvcContribs.UI.MenuBuilder` namespace.

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Daniel is correct that there's no way to make this shorter with existing helpers and methods, but if you're building a lot of menu links and they're all very similar you could write a small helper function:

```
@helper MenuLink(string linkText, string action = "Index", string controller = null)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(linkText, action, controller ?? linkText.Replace(" ", string.Empty))</li>
}
```

Now your code looks like:

```
<ul id="menu">
    @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")) {
        @MenuLink("Administration")
    }
</ul>
```

Those defaults help make things shorter, but if you need a different action from `Index` or your controller name isn't the same as the link text without spaces, it's easy to override them:

```
@MenuLink("Admin reports", "Admin", "Reports")
```

Going a step further, there are a couple of extension methods I use that would make this even shorter:

```
public static class HtmlStringConditionalExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString If(this IHtmlString value, bool evaluation)
    {
        return evaluation ? value : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    public static IHtmlString ForRoles(this IHtmlString value, params string[] roles)
    {
        return value.If(roles.Any(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole));
    }
}
```

And now you can write:

```
<ul id="menu">
    @MenuLink("Administration").ForRoles("admin")
</ul>
```